# React Set State within useEffect refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My application has a strange bug and I think it's to do with asnyc - where by if I navigate to a new page by clicking on an element my page data renders correctly.

However, if I refresh said page I get errors where my data is undefined - I think that's to do with react not having enough time to render the state change?

Is there a way to get around this - perhaps I'm trying to set my state incorrectly within a useEffect however, I want to update on "componentDidMount"?

Here is my useEffect code

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentData(getLibraryFromId(currentID, data));

});
```

Usage:

```
<img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${currentData.backdrop_path}`} alt='' />
```

Comment: Is getLibraryFromId a promise? or a method which returns a result?

Comment: Also - your useEffect has no array parameters, which means it will run on every change. Ideally you want to pass an empty array to imply it will only ever be on first load.useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentData(getLibraryFromId(currentID, data));
}, []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting data from API right so before that you need to add check if object is blank or not if blank then render nothing or display placeholder image.

```
      {currentData?.backdrop_path && (
        <img
          src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${currentData.backdrop_path}`}
          alt=""
        />
      )}
```

Comment: Yep that'll do it and makes sense! Thanks man!